# Codeanywhere container is either not there any more or lost its ssh connection

Tags: ssh, containers, codeanywhere

I have been working on a website using wordpress on codeanywhere for a few weeks. Suddenly yesterday morning the container it is in would not start anymore. I have other containers with wordpress sites under construction on codeanywhere and they are still functioning. I have noticed in the container information that the containers that are still working for these sites have a link next to "ssh access on", while the container that is not working has no such link. Could this mean that the link has been lost due to the SSH server being down. The links on the other sites are to different numbered SSH links so I don't dare trying to enter that container information in the "new connection" section of the non-functioning container.

I might be barking up the wrong tree. This is the first real problem I have had with codeanywhere but it worries me that something might happen to my other sites. Which I have now thoroughly backed up by downloading the all-one-migration files from wordpress. The website I can't open had a couple of days work not backed up off-line, I have now reentered that work (I think).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a [few reports](https://twitter.com/Jilu19881/status/1299668348293111810) or containers [not being accessible through SSH](https://twitter.com/justjamesdev/status/1299825144454623234), so it is possible it is a punctual issue.

A [Codeanywhere SSH/SFTP setting](https://docs.codeanywhere.com/#sftp-ssh) should be always available.